# "Read" Confirmation Button on Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Fellow collegues

I tried to implement a simple button inside a Joomla article to see which registered users have read an article and which didn't. I failed miserably, since my knowledge about PHP is honestly too low.

It should be possible to have a reading confirmation button on selected articles, so that the superior can check who has already read important information and who has not.

I was thinking of using php for getting the articleid, userid and a read field to construct a table in MySQLi, and depending on whether it is read or not, read will be either true or false.
the table is constructed already, but filling in the right information really leaves me hanging.
Now Problems occuring:
To fill in every user for each article which should've been confirmed automatically is impossible for me. I know that i can get a users username with the command

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

but i dont want to get the current user. It should provide an overview of which users have read the article and which didn't.
I'm really lost in code fragments and I'm having trouble understanding what I could benefit from.

I've already used the search function and this topic already came up several times, but still it seemed to me that it hasn't been answered properly yet.

Has anyone done something similar in Joomla before and could give me a hint on how to get this done?
Or does anyone know an extension which could handle the problem?
Any clarifying statements are warmly welcomed!

Greetings
Capo

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to use ajax, specifically, the com_ajax Joomla component. It's not as hard as you might think, and we have written a step by step guide on how to use the Joomla ajax component [here](https://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-use-joomlas-ajax-interface-component-com_ajax).

Essentially, you will need to create a button, which, when clicked, will send an ajax request to the server and update a table. The table that should be updated should be a custom table, containing the following fields: id, userid, contentid

The `id` field will be an autoincrement, the `userid` will be the ID of the user who read the article, and the `contentid` will be the ID of the article that the user has read.

Once you have the data in the table, you can then display it anyway you like!

Comment: Hey there itoctopus 
I was trying to get through a solution with your tutorial, but some things did not work out for me that well, either because i'm writing in the wrong files and/or my table in the DB is set wrong. Am i right to create 3 files, an xml, html file and the actual php file?
Thank you for clearing up the quesiton